# C# new class with a constructor parameter that references class it is being created in

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create a new class with the parameter for the constructor being the class it's created in? I tried the 'this' keyword but am getting the error: "keyword this is not available in the current context"

The code is basically what I am trying to do. The player needs a reference to its Game class.

```
class Player
{
      Game referenceGame;

      public Player(Game game)
      {
           referenceGame = game;
      }
         
}


class Game
{
      public Player player1 = new Player(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to `this` in a field initializer, that's all. You can do so from a constructor body though - so you just need to change the `Game` class to:

```cs
class Game
{
    public Player player1;

    public Game()
    {
        player1 = new Player(this);
    }
}
```

(As a side note, I'd strongly advise against using public fields, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it what you are looking for ?

```
class Player
{
    Game referenceGame;
    public Player(Game game)
    {
        referenceGame = game;
    }
}

class Game
{
    Player player1;
    public Game()
    {
        player1 = new Player(this);
    }
}
```